# Add Multiple shortcut key in Accelerator for single menu item in electron js

Tags: electron

There is menu in electron with three items View,Delete,Copy. for delete I want use three shortcut keys (Delete ,backspace, D).

How can I add multiple shortcut key in single menu item.

```html
{
    label: 'App',
    submenu: [
      {  label: 'View', accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+V', click: (item, focusedWindow) => _menuClick(focusedWindow, 'undo')},
      {  label: 'Delete', accelerator: 'Delete', click: (item, focusedWindow) => _menuClick(focusedWindow, 'undo')},
      { label: 'Copy', accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+C', click: (item, focusedWindow) => _menuClick(focusedWindow, 'undo')},
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can do with visible key in electron menu lik this

```html
{
    label: 'App',
    submenu: [
      {  label: 'View', accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+V'},
      {  label: 'Delete', accelerator: 'Delete'},
      {  label: 'Delete', accelerator: 'D', visible:false},
    ]
  },
```